# NSCoder and custom types

Tags: types, nscoder

How do you use NSCoder to encode and decode custom types?

For example, how would you use NSCoder with an instance of "`STATE`" where:

```
typedef enum { ON, OFF } STATE;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can treat them as integers as they are implicitly assigned integer values:

```
- (void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder {
  ...
  [coder encodeInt:type forKey:@"state"];
}

- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder {
  ...
  state = [coder decodeIntForKey:@"state"];
}
```

Comment: Except that a change in the order internally in the enum would break the coding.

Comment: And what class do you put these methods?  They are types, not objects...  `NSKeyedArchiver`?

Comment: To support encoding and decoding of instances, a class must adopt the NSCoding protocol and implement its methods. An object being encoded or decoded is responsible for encoding and decoding its state.

Comment: You can encode an additional "objectVersion" identifier to account for differences that may occur in enum order as the object architecture evolves.  An enum is also signed, so you can squeeze in negative values which may help in some circumstances.