# NSCoder: encoding enum without using NS_ENUM

Tags: ios, serialization, enums, encode

I don't want to force my users to update to iOS 6 and hence I wanted to find a way to use NSCoder with custom types and enumerations.

I have found [this article](http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/) that explains the recently introduced NS_ENUM macro, that basically makes it easier to the runtime library to retrieve the the metadata of the custom enumeration / type.

Is there an **alternative way** to encode custom enumerations?

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029760/nscoder-and-custom-types), is encoding as INT all I need to do? Enumerations are int but I am not sure if they can change to int32 or int64.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, encode it as an int and you should be fine. You could create a NSNumber with its value and then encode it. That would be the most common case.

Answer (score 1):

**Just encode the value as NSNUMBER**. Use this for any version of iOS.

```
 // #pragma mark Protocolo NSCoding
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(nonnull NSCoder *)aCoder {
     [aCoder encodeObject:@(self.customValue) forKey:@"customKey"];
  }

- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(nonnull NSCoder *)aDecoder { 
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.customValue = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"customKey"];
    }
    return self;
  }
```